Strange visible margin around Qmenu in lxqt
I've been tweaking with the linux UI for quite a bit and after a while I noticed a strange margin around the qmenu of the panel isn't margin supposed to be transparent, now the strange thing is that the main menu margin is still transparent !! I don't why, the settings of the panel qss are as shown in the image, at first I didn't know anything about css but when I noticed the problem I read some things and still don't know how to solve it any help ?


